# AttributeError at /users/register/ Manager isn't available; 'auth.User' has been swapped for 'userty.MyUser'

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, registration

I get this error whenver I try to register a new user from my website.
I have two types of users (Athlete and Host). Ive created their models as follows

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, BaseUserManager
from django.db import models
from COMBAT_CON_F import settings


class MyUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def normalize_email(self, email):
        email_parts = email.split('@')
        domain = email_parts[-1].lower()
        username = '@'.join(email_parts[:-1])
        return f'{username}@{domain}'
    
    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The Email field must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        return self.create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

class MyUser(AbstractUser):
    #objects = MyUserManager()
    is_athlete = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_host = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class Athlete(models.Model):
    GENDER_CHOICES = (
        ('M', 'Male'),
        ('F', 'Female'),
    )
    WEIGHT_CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
        ('Straw Weight', 'Straw Weight'),
        ('Fly Weight', 'Fly Weight'),
        ('Bantam Weight', 'Bantam Weight'),
    )
    user = models.OneToOneField('userty.MyUser', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    email = models.EmailField(null=True, default='example@example.com')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    profile_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='athlete_pics/', null=True, blank=True)
    contact_number = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField()
    age = models.IntegerField()
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
    height = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2)
    weight = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2)
    weight_category = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=WEIGHT_CATEGORY_CHOICES)
    fighting_style = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    club_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    coach_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    record = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
    

class Host(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField('userty.MyUser', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    email = models.EmailField(null=True, default='example@example.com')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    contact_number = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    organization_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    events_hosted = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email' 
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

this is my view for registration

```
def register(request):
    form = MyUserCreationForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MyUserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('home')
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form': form})
```

```
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/register/

Django Version: 3.2.18
Python Version: 3.11.0
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'events',
 'userty']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\SHRUTI\SEM_6\PROJECT\COMBAT_CON_F\myvenv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\SHRUTI\SEM_6\PROJECT\COMBAT_CON_F\myvenv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\SHRUTI\SEM_6\PROJECT\COMBAT_CON_F\myvenv\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\SHRUTI\SEM_6\PROJECT\COMBAT_CON_F\userty\views.py", line 18, in register
    if form.is_valid():
  File "C:\SHRUTI\SEM_6\PROJECT\COMBAT_CON_F\myvenv\Lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 175, in is_valid
    return self.is_bound and not self.errors
  File "C:\SHRUTI\SEM_6\PROJECT\COMBAT_CON_F\myvenv\Lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 170, in errors
    self.full_clean()
  File "C:\SHRUTI\SEM_6\PROJECT\COMBAT_CON_F\myvenv\Lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 374, in full_clean
    self._post_clean()
  File "C:\SHRUTI\SEM_6\PROJECT\COMBAT_CON_F\myvenv\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\forms.py", line 117, in _post_clean
    super()._post_clean()
  File "C:\SHRUTI\SEM_6\PROJECT\COMBAT_CON_F\myvenv\Lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 413, in _post_clean
    self.instance.full_clean(exclude=exclude, validate_unique=False)
  File "C:\SHRUTI\SEM_6\PROJECT\COMBAT_CON_F\myvenv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 1236, in full_clean
    self.clean()
  File "C:\SHRUTI\SEM_6\PROJECT\COMBAT_CON_F\myvenv\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 371, in clean
    self.email = self.__class__.objects.normalize_email(self.email)
  File "C:\SHRUTI\SEM_6\PROJECT\COMBAT_CON_F\myvenv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 187, in __get__
    raise AttributeError(

Exception Type: AttributeError at /users/register/
Exception Value: Manager isn't available; 'auth.User' has been swapped for 'userty.MyUser'
```

this is my whole error traceback

```
class MyUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
user_type = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[('athlete', 'Athlete'), ('host', 'Host')])

def save(self, commit=True):
    user = super().save(commit=False)
    if self.cleaned_data.get('user_type') == 'athlete':
        user.is_athlete = True
    elif self.cleaned_data.get('user_type') == 'host':
        user.is_host = True
    if commit:
        user.save()
    return user
```

this is my form

settings.py:

```
from pathlib import Path
import os

ROOT_URLCONF = 'COMBAT_CON_F.urls'

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'users',
    'events',
    'userty',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]



TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
                'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'COMBAT_CON_F.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}

validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME':     'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME':     'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME':     'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME':     'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Calcutta'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


STATIC_URL = '/static/'

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'userty.MyUser'

LOGIN_URL = '/login/'
```

I have no clue why i'm seeing this error. I dont even know what to try because i'm new to django

Answer (score 0):

You have to uncomment this line:

```py
#objects = MyUserManager()
```

And have you set `AUTH_USER_MODEL` to "userty.MyUser" in your settings.py ?

This properties are useless:

```py
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ()
```

They are useful only for child AbstractUser model

Comment: i'm getting the same error after making these changes

Comment: yes i've set AUTH_USER_MODEL to userty.MyUser
Made these changes too but still the same

Comment: Could you show your settings ? I assume that you restarted your django server after modifying your settings file?

Comment: i've put up my settings.py